# Remember uncommitted changes

Tags: mercurial

I have some uncommitted changes `C` in my repo. I would like remember that changes in any way and get clean code (without that changes), make a little change and commit it. Now, I would like to recover my changes `C` and continue working on it. I know that I can deal with it using a lot of ways, but that ways are irritating. How to do it using mercurial?

So, to be more precise I need something like a stack:

1. Working on the code. Remember changes `C` on the stack.
2. `hg update --clean`
3. Make a change `C2`. Commit it.
4. Pop from stack a changeset `C` and work on it. But, now the repositorium contains committed change `C2` and uncommitted `C`. It may cause that I need to merge but I expect that this merge will be invisible from the point of view repositorium.

Answer (score 3):

While you certainly can work with mercurial queues, there's IMHO an easier and nicer way: change your default phase to secret and work with those commits like normal commits. Commits in phase secret are mutable and will not be exposed by push and pull commands acting on the repo.

This process has the advantage that you do not need to change your workflow - whether you work with commits you want to share (phase draft or public), or whether you still consider them work-in-progress and keep them locally only.

Additionally if you enable the evolve extension, you gain several benefits: it becomes even easier to amend commits and evolve (thus rebase) all child commits which depend on it.

The big advantage over the use of the mercurial queues is that you can make full use of the inbuild merge features - thus if the underlaying code changes, rebasing the new changesets is WAY easier and natural than using queues and hg shelve.

See the [introduction](https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/88203) to [hg phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases) and [changeset evolution](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangesetEvolution) which needs the [evolve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension).

Comment: Secret phase is no more mutable than draft phase, and only a head commit can be altered (via --amend).  Also FYI on mq, you can rebase an applied patch queue and it will use the merge tool as well.  evolve is still listed as experimental so that should be considered as well.

Comment: Yes and no. What you miss is the actual gain of the evolve extension: enabling it, you can amend any commit - and subsequently only need to 'evolve' all children of the now altered one (which is done with one command for all). It has the additional benefit that you don't loose the history as with mq (where you only have that when introducing a new repo for the patch queue)
While secret and draft can both be altered - draft commits will be shared and might then become immutable. Thus use phase secret for those you don't want to share.

Comment: I know what evolve is, and like it.  I'm just saying it is considered experimental.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Mercurial Queues extension in your `mercurial.ini` or `.hgrc` file:

```
[extensions]
mq =
```

Then you can,

```
hg qnew save      # save work in progress as a temporary commit
hg qpop           # remove that commit
```

Make some more changes....

```
hg ci -m "new changes"
hg qpush                     # push the saved commit back.
hg qfinish -a                # convert all temp commits to full commits.
```

You can also enable the shelve extension:

```
[extensions]
shelve =
```

Then you can:

```
hg shelve     # "put away" current uncommitted changes.
*do other work*
hg unshelve   # bring the shelved changes back
```

See `hg help mq` and `hg help shelve` for more info.

Comment: I don't think we should encourage more people to learn evolve. Let's point people towards evolve instead. Evolve has less conceptual overhead and is much easier to learn. MQ is also deprecated by upstream mercurial (deprecated in the sense that no one is working on improving it and it will not get any new features in the future).

Comment: I've used evolve, and like it, but it still has its quirks.  I don't think suggesting using mature extensions was worth a downvote.  I think you mistated your first sentence, however :^)

Answer (score -1):

I've tried shelve, mq as described in other answers but to be honest I generally stick with:

```
hg diff > saved.patch # This assumes you've not aliased diff to a UI!!!
hg update -C
.. work 
hg patch -f --no-commit saved.patch # I alias this for less typing
.. continue
```

Less book-keeping involved, its never gone wrong unlike shelve, and the patch itself is more easily portable. Just *use common-sense* and either make sure the patch applies fully, or use the `--partial` option and manually complete the patch.